# Want to use .sendKeys(Keys.ENTER); but not a text field

Tags: javascript, java, automation, driver

There is an element that is not a text box or a button, there are just a list of items. And me sending enter on the webpage would clear my list of orders from the UI.

I was trying to use

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath_name").sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

I tried to `.click()` the same element and it works..
But when I try to `sendKeys(Enter)`, it says element is not interactable.

All the examples of internet only explained about sending Enter key after typing something or inside a `textField`.

I tried `js.executeScript` as well.. still element is not interactable is the issue I get.

Answer (score 0):

Please use that sendkeys on different element, your current accessing element is not visible on the page. so try it on visible element in your page.